# Set PageSize, PageNumber and switch between pages

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, ado

I have a page with several hundreds or thousands of items. Webpage size is manually set by user, choosing how many items s/he want to see (options are 25,50,100,200). Depending on that, items will appear in several pages.

To verify each item, I have an SQL. I want to check only the items which are currently on screen, i.e. items 26 to 50 out of 100.

I tried next:

```
ItemsOnPage = mybrowser.webelement(...).GetROProperty("innertext")
Set aRecordSet= objconnection.Execute(Query)
    aRecordSet.PageSize = ItemsOnPage 
    print aRecordSet.PageNumber
```

`aRecordSet.PageNumber` stays as -1, dependless on PageSize, as well as if I do not set PageSize.

Also, need to set PageNumber based on current page on Web:

```
    wCurrentPage = mybrowser.webElement(...).GetROProperty("innertext")
```

I tried next options:

```
aRecordSet.AbsolutePage = wCurrentPage
aRecordSet.AbsolutePosition = 2+(ItemsOnPage *(wCurrentPage-1))
```

These commands returned errors:Operation is not allowed when the object is open. And

```
aRecordSet.CursorLocation = 1+(ItemsOnPage *(wCurrentPage-1))
```

returned "Current Recordset does not support bookmarks."

How it can be realized?

**UPD:** The query to get data is:

```
SELECT * FROM tblCustomerMetricData
WHERE RunDate = '"&webGetDate&"' AND
CustomerID in 
(SELECT CustomerID from [tblCustomers] 
where RegionID in (SELECT RegionID FROM [tblRegion] 
WHERE RegionName = '"&webRegionName&"')) OR CustomerID in (SELECT CustomerID from [tblCustomers] 
where CustomerName = '"&webCustomerName&"'))
```

Anything starting with "web" considered as variable getting values from webpage as user sets. Query run by UFT.

Comment: What is your query? Have you included the full code or is there anything missing which could turn out to be important?

Comment: Added query to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to configure my Recordset - not sure if it was because I could not or because provider did not support.
I moved on with this solution:

```
pagesnumber = mybrowser(...).Webedit(...).GetROProperty("innertext") 'get pages on web
for p = 1 to pagesnumber-1
for r = 0 to webtable.rowcount
for c = 0 to webtable.columncount(1)

(comparing by cell by row here)

next 'loop columncount
Recordset.MoveNext
next 'loop rowcount
next 'loop pagesnumber
```

Thus, I dont need to set pages or recordnumber for Recordset.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can configure Recordsets for use. We do pagination on our website at the ADO client side and it works perfectly. Try adding the following after you've established your database connection:

```
objconnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
```

If `adUseClient` is not defined, set it to `3`.

[Here are the docs for CursorLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee252442(v=bts.10).aspx).